# Создать новую коллекцию на основании данных другой

Tags: mongodb

Имею коллекцию в которую добавлены данные из реляционной базы данных типа

ID NAME PARENT_ID ...

Хочу на основании связки ID и PARENT_ID (родительская задача) создать нормальную структуру типа
ID NAME ..
    ID NAME 
        ID NAME 
связав по ID и PARENT_ID
не пойму как это сделать выборкой и записью.

Answer (score 0):

выборку сделал

```
db.collect01.aggregate([
{
$lookup:
{
    from: "collect01",
    localField: 'ID',   
    foreignField: 'PARENT_ID',
    as: 'CHILDREN'
}
}
])
```

Теперь вопрос как это корректно записать в другую коллекцию (или в эту же). Нашел только вариант поместить результат в курсор а потом записать
db.collection.insert(cursor.toArray());
но так долго пишется